# Console App not working when called in powershell script using Msbuilds

Tags: c#, powershell, msbuild, console-application

I am using MsBuilds to run a powershell script that further calls a console application.When running the build, the powershell script runs but does not further call the console application, neither does it throw any exception.

My **msbuild argument** is

`<Exec Command=" winrs -r:http://$(DatabaseServerName):$(ServerPort) powershell -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; invoke-command -scriptblock {&amp;&apos;$(ScriptLocation)&apos; &apos;$(fromVersion)&apos; &apos;$(toVersion)&apos; &apos;$(Args)&apos;  &apos;$(DatabaseDriveLetter):\Temp&apos;  &apos;$(DefaultLanguageCode)&apos; } &quot;"/>`

My **powershell script** has this argument

```
'$csvProc = Start-Process $dir -ArgumentList $arguments;'
```

here $dir has the path to the console application : say D:\Temp\consoleapp.exe

When I run the powerhsell script from cmd using the build arguments manually, it works fine but not it does not work when the MsBuild runs on itself.

Comment: You have to narrow your problem down. Find out if the line before/after this line are executed. Find out if this line you are having problem with produce any strerr or stdout output. Find out if the process of your console app starts at all with a tool such as procmon.

Comment: I tried writing text before and after this line and both the commands got executed. '$text | Add-Content 'D:\file.txt';
                $csvProc = Start-Process $dir -ArgumentList $arguments;
                $arguments | Add-Content 'D:\file.txt';' my file has data from both the add-content commands

Comment: So you are executing this command *remotely*. When you run it from the command line are you running it locally or remotely?

Comment: yes, when i run this remotely, i can replicate the issue. the powershell script still runs but the console application is not called from it. If i run it from the same server, everything works fine though.

Comment: You probably forgot to copy your app to the remote server. Log the output from your powershell command as I suggest earlier and you most likely will see an error complaining about just that.

Comment: the console app has its own logs if executed. Since there are no console logs generated, I believe that the console app is not being executed. Also, is there a way i can log if any errors occur in executing '$csvProc = Start-Process $dir -ArgumentList $arguments;'? I am using try catch around it and it is not generating any exception.